# How to manage JWT after redirect?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have a flow where user enters some credentials on side keycloak sso system and after correct inputs it is redirected to frontend through proxy and nginx ingress. The frontend needs to verify if jwt token is there. Which is the suitable way to provide jwt in this case so that the frontend then can store it in local/session storage and then use it? Redirecting with token in url is unacceptable for security reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little you say, I would advise you not to do this. If there's something in play here that I'm not seeing to make this safe, you could perhaps pass the JWT in an HTTP response header or add it to the query string. The NGINX proxy may help with this. Then, when the app loads, it can find the token in the query string or header and be able to save it.

Comment: I thought that it is impossible to redirect with header..please correct me if I'm wrong. When proxy redirect to ingress and ingress to clien..how I will be able to provide headers from nginx map..

Comment: The headers from any previous responses won't be available of course, but you say "after correct inputs it is redirected to frontend through proxy and nginx ingress". So, I was thinking that request included the JWT somehow. If so, the NGINX proxy could set a response header or update the query string. If that's not the case, perhaps you can edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Maybe I will provide it in body, I guess, so to say to read it from there after all this redirects